# Jquery Dialog Open Iframe and Close When Click Else Where

Tags: jquery

I have a button and when user clicks, it pops up the dialog box with a iframe which loads the Detail page (see below).  I am able to close this popup on the top-right X button, but I like to also close this popup when user clicks outside of the popup box.

I see jQuery codes that can close the DIV when user clicks outside, but the DIV has to be static in the body page.  my OpenIframe function codes below is dynamically creating the DIV with user clicks, so I am don't know how to make it close when user clicks outside.

My jQuery codes to open dialog with iFrame.

```
function OpenIframe(url, recordId, width, height, event, pagetitle) {
    if (event.preventDefault)
        event.preventDefault();
    else
        event.returnValue = false;

    var page = url + "?" + recordId + "=" + encodeURIComponent($('span[id$="' + recordId + '"]').text());
    //alert(page);
    //var pagetitle = $(this).attr("title");
    var $dialog = $('<div id="dialog"  style="text-align:center;"></div>') 
    .html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"  frameBorder="0"   align="center"> </iframe>')
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        height: height,
        width: width,
        title: pagetitle
    });
    $dialog.dialog('open');
}
```

I see people use this code below to close the popup when user clicks outside, but it only works if the DIV is statically put in the body of the page.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#dialog").dialog({
            bgiframe: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 100,
            modal: true,
            open: function(){
                jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click',function(){
                    jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');
                })
            }
        });
    });
```

If possible, please help me modify the code to make it works?

Thanks!

Comment: is it possible for you to create a jsFiddle?

Comment: Here is the jsFiddle (first time created it, let me know if I am doing wrong). http://jsfiddle.net/pwywhztu/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/thecbuilder/Ltcuqpkz/5/

```
    jQuery('body').on('click', '.ui-widget-overlay', function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog('close');
    });
```

add this in `open` callback to close your modal.

Also add

```
<div id="dialog"  style="text-align:center;"></div>
```

in `body` only. You are again and again adding the same `id` `div`.

And if don't want to add the `div` in `body` then when closing `dialog` also `.remove()` the `div`.

Complete **js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $("#showD").click(function () {
        OpenIframe("test");
    });
});

function OpenIframe(pagetitle) {
    var $dialog = jQuery('#dialog')
        .html('Here goes iFrame')
        .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
        title: pagetitle,
        open: function (a, b) {
            jQuery('body').on('click', '.ui-widget-overlay', function () {
                $('#dialog').dialog('destroy');
            });
        }
    });
    $dialog.dialog('open');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.ui-widget-overlay').live('click', function() {
     $('#dialog').dialog( "close" );
});
```